# Why does using t-test on multiple groups of means will increase the alpha of the test?

Tags: anova, t-test

I saw a video about ANOVA today.
It said that we should use ANOVA instead of t-test when we have more than 2 groups of sample to test.
This is because if we us t-test instead of ANOVA, it will be inaccurate due to the alpha increases.

Why is this the case?

Comment: [Mandatory XKCD about jelly beans](https://xkcd.com/882/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANOVA is used to detect a difference in means of 3 or more independent
groups. It tests whether the mean of any group differs from the overall mean.

T-test is used to compare the means between 2 groups. So to compare e.g. 3 groups (A,B,C) with each other using T-tests, you would require 3 tests (A-B, A-C, B-C).

The problem: each single test is associated with a type 1 error (probability of observing a false positive). This means that you get a significant p-value and therefore falsely reject an actually true null hypothesis. Using a significance level of 0.05 (or 5%), you would get 1 in 20 (i.e. 5%) tests to be significant simply by chance. The probability for type 1 error increases with the number of tests performed by

`1-(1-alpha)^n`, with *n* being the number of tests.

So for example, your type 1 error probability using the 3 T-tests above with *alpha* being *0.05* would be

`1-(1-0.05)^3 = 0.1426`,

and with 20 tests it would increase to

`1-(1-0.05)^20 = 0.6415`

This is much higher than if you would use a single test: `1-(1-0.05)^1 = 0.05`

To account for this increase in probability of type 1 error (what you refer to as "alpha of the test"), you can adjust the p-values obtained from your multiple tests using for example the *Bonferroni*, *Holm*, or *Benjamini-Hochberg* methods (and many more).

Comment: How is 1-(1-alpha)^n derived?

Comment: Your _alpha_ of ```0.05```, is the probability of type1 error if you use a single test. Accordingly, you will NOT observe type1 error with a probability of ```P1=1-0.05=0.95``` (in a single test). If you have multiple tests, you miltiply your probability ```P1``` according to the number of tests. So with 3 tests, it becomes ```P1*P1*P1=0.857```. So if ```0.857``` is the probability to NOT observe type1 error, then ```1-0.857 = 0.143``` is the probabilty of type1 error. Therefore, you could say that your _alpha_ increased from 0.05 (using a single test) to 0.143 (using 3 tests).

Comment: Bravo Roman. Lets go play bowling some time.